# Repetição de código no mesmo método

Tags: c#

Tenho um método que gera algumas informações. Como eu tinha pressa para entregar, fiz e enviei. Bem, acontece, que vendo o código com mais cuidado, percebi o quanto está deselegante. Ele foi feito para atender uma especificação e como foi alterado isso tive que alterar o código. A regra atual é  seguinte:
Tenho um método que trata arquivos da **FarmInterna**. O mesmo vale para a **FarmExterna**. Acontece, que agora eu preciso criar antes da pasta **FarmInterna**, dois novos ***folders***. **Homologacao e Producao**. Em cada pasta(**Homologacao e Producao**) deverá haver duas pastas: **FarmInterna e FarmExterna**. Vou falar apenas da FarmInterna, que vai valer também para a Externa. Os mesmos arquivos que gero no path: `...Homolagacao/FarmInterna/web/...` são os mesmos para: `...Producao/FarmInterna/web/...`. Isso deixou meu código extremamente feio e deselegante. Como eu faço para não duplicar o código como está? Existe algum pattern para isso? Abaixo meu código. Onde existe a letra ***H*** refere-se a Homolagação e ***P*** a produção.

```
private void CriaPastaFarmInterna()
        {
            string novo_path_H  = caminho_original + @"\Destino\Temp\Homologacao\FarmInterna\web";
            string novo_path_P  = caminho_original + @"\Destino\Temp\Producao\FarmInterna\web";
            string path_files   = caminho_original + @"\Destino\Temp";

            DirectoryInfo dirInfoH = new DirectoryInfo(novo_path_H);
            DirectoryInfo dirInfoP = new DirectoryInfo(novo_path_P);

            int indice = 1;

            if (dirInfoH.Exists == false)
                Directory.CreateDirectory(novo_path_H);

            if (dirInfoP.Exists == false)
                Directory.CreateDirectory(novo_path_P);

            List<String> myFiles = Directory.GetFiles(caminho_original + @"\Destino\Temp\web", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();

            List<String> myDirectoriesH = Directory.GetDirectories(caminho_original + @"\Destino\Temp\web").ToList();
            List<String> myDirectoriesP = Directory.GetDirectories(caminho_original + @"\Destino\Temp\web").ToList();

            var diretorios_H = myDirectoriesH.Where(d => !d.Contains("FarmInterna"));
            var diretorios_P = myDirectoriesP.Where(d => !d.Contains("FarmInterna"));

            try
            {
                foreach (string file in myFiles)
                {
                    FileInfo mFile = new FileInfo(file);
                    string newFileH = novo_path_H + (file.Replace(caminho_original + @"\Destino\Temp\web", ""));
                    string newFileP = novo_path_P + (file.Replace(caminho_original + @"\Destino\Temp\web", ""));

                    if (!Directory.Exists(newFileH))
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(newFileH));

                    if (!Directory.Exists(newFileP))
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(newFileP));

                    if (new FileInfo(newFileH).Exists == false)
                        mFile.CopyTo(newFileH);

                    if (new FileInfo(newFileP).Exists == false)
                        mFile.CopyTo(newFileP);
                }

                RenomearWebConfig(novo_path_H, "H");
                RenomearWebConfig(novo_path_P, "P");
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {}
        }
```

Comment: Minha idéia inicial, seria tirar as linhas duplicadas nesse código, tendo em mente que eles criam novos diretorios e o arquivo sendo repetição nos dois diretórios criados. Você iria mudar principalmente o desempenho e o número de linhas diminuindo consequentemente. Como o diretório é novo e os arquivos são novos faz uma verificação somente em uma das pastas. Você pode fazer o seguinte, rodar essa rotina para uma pasta e no final copiar os arquivos para a outra pasta também é uma idéia. Você pode usar [Adapter](http://www.dofactory.com/net/adapter-design-pattern), mas, não precisa ao meu ver

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O **refactoring para eliminação de código duplicado** é bastante simples:

- **1)** Declare um novo método (ele vai receber o código que generaliza a solução que hoje está duplicada).
- **2)** Percorra o código do método original, movendo cada linha duplicada para dentro do novo método. Veja bem: **movendo!** Não é copiando e colando, é recortando e colando. Escolha um padrão de linhas a mover; por exemplo: mova para o novo método as linhas que tratam **"homologação"**, deixando as linhas que tratam **"produção"** no método original.
- **3)** As linhas que estruturam a execução (condições, loops, try-catch...) eventualmente não estão duplicadas - estas você copia para o novo método em vez de mover.
- **4)** As linhas movidas para o novo método não vão compilar pois precisam de variáveis que não existem naquele contexto. Declare cada uma destas variáveis inexistentes como parâmetros deste novo método. Agora o novo método já compila.
- **5)** No código do novo método, substitua por parâmetros as constantes e literais que sejam exclusivos de cada execução, de modo a tornar genéricas as linhas que usam estas constantes e literais.
- **6)** Percorra novamente o método original e substitua as linhas que já foram replicadas no novo método por uma chamada a este novo método, passando os parâmetros conforme exigidos por ele (no caso, os parâmetros referentes a "produção").
- **7)** Faça mais uma chamada ao novo método, passando como parâmetro as variáveis da outra chamada (no caso, os parâmetros referentes a "homologação").
- **8)** Renomeie os parâmetros e variáveis internas do novo método para expressar sua natureza de solução genérica tanto para "produção" quanto para "homologação".

**Pronto.** Agora você tem o método original gerando os argumentos necessários para serem passados nas duas chamadas ao novo método.

Este passo a passo é genérico e pode ser utilizado para qualquer refactoring deste tipo.

**Dica:** Se você estiver disposto, acrescente o **Passo Zero** no começo da lista, que é um teste unitário cobrindo a funcionalidade e que vai garantir que ela continua produzindo os mesmos resultados depois do refactoring.

Seguindo este passo-a-passo, o código fica assim:

```
private void CriaPastaFarmInternaEExterna()
{
    string novo_path_H = caminho_original + @"\Destino\Temp\Homologacao\FarmInterna\web";
    string novo_path_P = caminho_original + @"\Destino\Temp\Producao\FarmInterna\web";

    List<String> myFiles = Directory.GetFiles(caminho_original + @"\Destino\Temp\web", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();

    CriaPastaFarm(novo_path_H, myFiles, "H");
    CriaPastaFarm(novo_path_P, myFiles, "P");
}

private void CriaPastaFarm(string novo_path, IEnumerable<string> files, string ambiente)
{
    DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(novo_path);

    if (dirInfo.Exists == false)
        Directory.CreateDirectory(novo_path);

    List<String> myDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(caminho_original + @"\Destino\Temp\web").ToList();
    var diretorios = myDirectories.Where(d => !d.Contains("FarmInterna"));

    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        FileInfo mFile = new FileInfo(file);
        string newFile = novo_path + (file.Replace(caminho_original + @"\Destino\Temp\web", ""));

        if (!Directory.Exists(newFile))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(newFile));

        if (new FileInfo(newFile).Exists == false)
            mFile.CopyTo(newFile);
    }
    RenomearWebConfig(novo_path, ambiente);
}
```

Obs: deixei de fora as variáveis *indice* e *path_files* que não estavam sendo utilizadas. Também deixei de fora o *try-catch* porque do jeito que você usou, limpando a exceção, pode causar problemas.

Obs2: Há várias coisas que podem ser melhoradas, como por exemplo substituir por um *enum* os literais *"H"* e *"P"* a fim de aumentar a expressividade do código; substituir a comparação `(condição == false)` pela negação da condição, `(!condição)`, que é mais usual; eliminar as repetições de caminho de arquivo (*@"\Destino\Temp\web"*); etc.

Comment: Caffé, ainda não implementei a seu exemplo, mas foi extremamente útil para mim. Amanhã(terça-feira) vou fazer o que você sugeriu.

Comment: Caffé, como ficaria para a FarmExterna?

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, centraliza o código repetido num novo método, e chama este método 2 vezes passando os parâmetros que alteram o comportamento do programa.

```
private void CriaPastaFarmInterna()
        {
            NovoMetodo(caminho_original + @"\Destino\Temp\Homologacao\FarmInterna\web", 'H');
            NovoMetodo(caminho_original + @"\Destino\Temp\Producao\FarmInterna\web", 'P');


}

private void NovoMetodo(string novoPath, char letra) {

    DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(novoPath);    

    if (dirInfo.Exists == false)
                Directory.CreateDirectory(novoPath);

    List<String> myFiles = Directory.GetFiles(caminho_original + @"\Destino\Temp\web", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();

    List<String> myDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(caminho_original + @"\Destino\Temp\web").ToList();

    var diretorios = myDirectories.Where(d => !d.Contains("FarmInterna"));

    try
    {
        foreach (string file in myFiles)
        {
            FileInfo mFile = new FileInfo(file);
            string newFile = novoPath + (file.Replace(caminho_original + @"\Destino\Temp\web", ""));

            if (!Directory.Exists(newFile))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(newFile));


            if (new FileInfo(newFile).Exists == false)
                mFile.CopyTo(newFile);

        }

        RenomearWebConfig(novoPath, letra);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

você pode tentar da seguinte forma:

```
private void CriaPastaFarmInterna(string oldPath, string newPath)
{
    var oldDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(oldPath);
    var newDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(newPath);

    if (!oldDirectory.Exists)
        return false;       

    if (!diretorio.Exists)
        diretorio.Create();

    for (var subDirectory in oldDirectory.GetDirectories())
    {
        CriaPastaFarmInterna(subDirectory.FullName, newPath + @"\" + subDirectory.Name)
    }

    for (var oldFile in oldDirectory.GetFiles())
    {
        var newFile = new FileInfo(newDirectory.FullName + @"\" + oldFile.Name);
        if (!newFile.Exists)
            oldFile.CopyTo(newFile.FullName)
    }
}

private void CriaPastaFarmInterna()
{
    string oldPath   = caminho_original + @"\Destino\Temp\Web";
    string newPathH  = caminho_original + @"\Destino\Temp\Homologacao\FarmInterna\web";
    string newPathP  = caminho_original + @"\Destino\Temp\Producao\FarmInterna\web";

    try
    {
        CriaPastaFarmInterna(oldPath, newPathH);
        CriaPastaFarmInterna(oldPath, newPathP);

        RenomearWebConfig(novo_path_H, "H");
        RenomearWebConfig(novo_path_P, "P");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {           

    }
}
```